# Rust (Bittorrent): Failing at announcing, with response "Requested download is not authorized for use with this tracker"

Tags: url, rust, sha1, bittorrent, torrent

I'm trying to find peers in the Bittorrent network, but I'm getting the response "Requested download is not authorized for use with this tracker". The torrent file I'm trying to download is "Ubuntu 20.04.2.0 Desktop (64-bit)" and it can be found [here](https://ubuntu.com/download/alternative-downloads). I have checked against other Bittorrent-clients, and have confirmed that the `info_hash` is correct. I'm leaning towards that my error might be because of some incorrect url-encoding, but I'm not sure.

The networking part of code is using the [reqwest](https://crates.io/crates/reqwest) crate. To url-encode the `info_hash`, I'm using the [urlencode](https://crates.io/crates/urlencoding) crate. Here is the code for url-encoding and sending the GET request:

```rust
let client = reqwest::blocking::Client::new();
   
let info_hash_encoded = urlencoding::encode_binary(&torrent.info_hash).into_owned().to_uppercase();
let resp = client
    .get(&torrent.announce)
    .query(&[
        ("info_hash", info_hash_encoded.as_str()),
        ("peer_id", PEER_ID),
        ("port", PORT),
        ("uploaded", "0"),
        ("downloaded", "0"),
        ("compact", "1"),
        ("left", torrent.length.to_string().as_str()),
    ])
    .send()?
    .text()?;

println!("{:?}", resp);
```

Where `torrent.info_hash` is the info hash as a byte vector (Vec<u8>).

Here is how the *reqwest* response actually looks like:

```rust
Response { url: Url { scheme: "https", cannot_be_a_base: false, username: "", password: None, host: Some(Domain("torrent.ubuntu.com")), port: None, path: "/announce", query: Some("info_hash=K%25A4%25FB%25F7%2523%251A%253AF%250E%2586%2589%2527%2507%25D2%255C%2513U3%25A1J&peer_id=-rqbt01-jsbckj94ksj3&port=5035&uploaded=0&downloaded=0&compact=1&left=2877227008"), fragment: None }, status: 200, headers: {"date": "Sat, 17 Jul 2021 17:05:25 GMT", "server": "Apache/2.4.18 (Ubuntu)", "content-length": "85", "content-type": "text/plain", "pragma": "no-cache", "vary": "Accept-Encoding"} }
```

I first thought the problem might be because the `info_hash_encoded` was in lowercase hex, but after uppercasing it, I'm still recieving the same error. By the way, the info hash in hex-form is: `4ba4fbf7231a3a660e86892707d25c135533a16a`.

Thanks!

**Edit**: It turns out that the hash somehow got encoded twice, but I'm still having the same problem even after fixing that. Does anybody know what would be the correct url encoded info hash so I can compare it with what I currently have? I also tried implementing my own url encoding following [this spec](https://wiki.theory.org/BitTorrentSpecification#Tracker_HTTP/HTTPS_Protocol), but I am still recieving the same error.

Comment: Have you read https://askubuntu.com/a/957808 yet?

Comment: Yes @mmirate, and I've tried with different torrents, but I'm still recieving the same error.

Comment: You added an edit about the hash being encoded twice but you didn't update the error message you got.

Comment: I think the error was mainly the double encoding issue, but I've decided to recreate this small project. I'll edit my post if I can later confirm that the issue was indeed that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had two bugs that stopped this from working:

1. `info_hash` was being encoded twice, resulting in "%" characters being encoded to "%25".
2. Every non-numerical byte should be encoded as %<xx>, meaning "%7" should be "%07". I was missing leading zero's.

Here is what worked for me:

```rust
use std::error::Error;
use std::fmt::Write;

pub fn url_encode_bytes(content: &[u8]) -> Result<String, Box<dyn Error>> {
    let mut out: String = String::new();

    for byte in content.iter() {
        match *byte as char {
            '0'..='9' | 'a'..='z' | 'A'..='Z' | '.' | '-' | '_' | '~' => out.push(*byte as char),
            _ => write!(&mut out, "%{:02X}", byte)?,
        };
    }

    Ok(out)
}
```

I haven't figured out a nice solution to the double encoding issue, but currently I'm just creating the `info_hash` query manually like this:

```rust
let url_builder = ureq::get(&torrent.announce)
    .query("peer_id", PEER_ID)
    .query("port", PORT)
    .query("uploaded", "0")
    .query("downloaded", "0")
    .query("compact", "1")
    .query("left", LENGTH);

let url = format!(
    "{}{}",
    url_builder.url(),
    format!("&info_hash={}", url_encode_bytes(&torrent.info_hash)?)
);
```

I also switched from the [reqwest](https://crates.io/crates/reqwest) crate to the [ureq](https://crates.io/crates/ureq) crate.
The correct url-encoded hash (as far as I'm aware) is: `K%A4%FB%F7%23%1A%3Af%0E%86%89%27%07%D2%5C%13U3%A1j`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `byte_serialize()` in the [form_urlencoded](https://crates.io/crates/form_urlencoded) crate (which you're already depending on if you use [ureq](https://crates.io/crates/ureq)):

```rust
let info_hash_encoded: String = byte_serialize(&info_hash).collect();
```